# Reading Mifare 1k from a WinForm application

Tags: c#, smartcard, mifare

I have a really weird problem with reading Mifare 1k card from WinForm application. The reader I'm using is a PROMAG PCR-310U smart card reader.
 I use this code to read the card:

```
MifareReader.CommPort = 4;
MifareReader.PortOpen = true;
MifareReader.mfRequest();
MessageBox.Show(MifareReader.mfAnticollision().ToString());
MifareReader.mfHalt();
```

The code is placed inside the backgroundWorkers DoWork method, and the entire method looks like this:

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        while (!worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            MifareReader.CommPort = 4;
            MifareReader.PortOpen = true;
            MifareReader.mfRequest();
            CardID = MifareReader.mfAnticollision().ToString();                
            MifareReader.mfHalt();
            if (CardID != "0" && CardID != string.Empty)
            {
                e.Result = CardID;
                worker.CancelAsync();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The reader I'm using is a PROMAG PCR-310U smart card reader and GNetPlus and MifareReader dll's. I have an application where a parent form creates a child form. That child form reads the smart card's ID and sends it to the parent. The problem is this - the first time I create the child form, the reading process works perfectly but the second time (and every time after that) I create the child, the reader stops working - it returns "0" as the CardID whether the card is present or not. What could cause this error, and how would I fix it?

Comment: The problem most likely is that `MifareReader` has problems with multiple threads. But it is impossible to answer without knowning the code of `MifareReader`.

Comment: Unfortunately that class is a part of the MifareReader dll, and I don't have access to it's code only metadata

Comment: Is `mfRequest` a static method? Or is `MifareReader` a class instance?

Comment: MifareReader is an instance of the class (the class has the same name, but I changed the names in this question so it would make sense, I named it different in my code), so mfRequest (and Anticollision and Halt) can only be accessed trough an instance of that class.

Comment: Is there a `Dispose` method on that class?

Comment: No, I looked for that (Dispose, Close, Exit, nothing even similar). I tried to find some documentation on line for either of these dll's but the company which makes the reader is from Taiwan, so no luck so far.

Comment: Try `PortOpen = false;` at the end. I have the feeling that the old instance of the first child form still blocks access to the reader and thus prevents the second child form from successfully communicating with it.

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I think you need to contact the developers of that DLL or check the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll have to do that, but I was trying to avoid that solution, because it might slow my development a lot

Comment: You can open the dll in reflector or dotpeek and see the code....:P

Comment: @DanielHilgarth you were right, the PortOpen was the issue (when I tested after, I had another instance of the MifareReader blocking the same CommPort). Can you please put that comment as answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Could you please update the code to reflect your working solution, i seem to be in a similar situation, and would like to see a "working" sample

Comment: I can't post a working sample because I changed the approach quite a bit. Since my application fits "parent-child" paradigm (one root parent that displays child forms in its container), I created one instance of MifareReader object and open it when the parent is loaded, and pass it as a public member to the child forms that need it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answer, did you ever find some documentation for the two dll files? i seem to be stuck very early in this process, i simply want to test if the device works or not, but am only getting "0" out, i am constructing the MifareReader, then setting the CommPort, then Setting the PortOpen to true, then reading from mfAnticollision a few times, before closing again,

Comment: My company had some PDF's with description of the process of card reading that they got directly from the manufacturer but I can't find them. Post your code in an answer and I'll see if I can help you.

Comment: Well, as it is a question, i will post it on another Thread, i dont think i will make much sense to post it as a answer :), i will also be tagged mitfare and C#

Comment: ok, yust write the name of the thread in a comment so I know which one it is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790099/reading-mifare-data-using-mitfarereader-gnetplus-dll Thanks!

Comment: Oh! I'm too far to say I'm too late but I stuck in the game to read and write information via RFID PROMAG PCR310U. @NDraskovic have you completed the task for reading and writing? If yes please provide some chunks of code! Thank you. working code snippet will be more appreciated ramizjaved725@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the issue is the following:

After closing the first child form the `MifareReader` instance isn't disposed or otherwise knows that it no longer is required. That means that it still controls the reader and apparently this blocks access to all other instances trying to access that reader.
One such blocked instance is the `MifareReader` instance in the *second* child form you open.

Try telling the first instance that it no longer is required by closing the port via `PortOpen = false;`.