# What is the difference between closing an installed application and stopping the debugging process in VS 2010

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title states, I'm interested in differences between stopping the debugging process in the VS 2010 and closing that application after it is installed.
The reason I'm asking this is that I get a weird problem with my application - this application employs several parent-child form connections. The data transfer works fine, and this is the code I use to enable it:

In the child form:

```
public ParentForm Parent { get; set; }
```

And in parent form:

```
ChildForm CF = new ChildForm();
CF.ParentForm = this;
CF.ShowDialog();
```

In the parent form I mark the variables or methods that need to be shared as public, and the data transfer/modulation works fine. 
The problem I'm getting is with a smart card reader. It should be called from one of the child forms (specifically third "generation" child form), and simply read the cards ID number. The problem is that this works perfectly the first time the child form is created, but stops working completely every next time (the child form has no special method defined in its FromClosing or FormClosed methods). I managed to "cheat" my way out, and defined the reader specific data in the parent (root "generation") form, and it works properly now, but I'm worried about what will happen when I install the application (I can't start with testing yet because the destination workstations are not available to me yet) - to be specific, will the reader stop working the first time the user closes the application. So my question is what does the VS do when it starts/finishes with debugging, and can these conditions be duplicated in the release version of the application.

Thank you

Comment: _"So my question is what does the VS do when it starts/finishes with debugging"_ - I think you're really looking at the wrong problem there. I think you should address a real problem when it occurs, not ask a hip shooter question before the problem has even shown itself. Restarting the application will usually not do much different than restarting a debugging session.

Comment: You seem to have a bug in your code. Please show that code. It most likely has nothing to do with debugging, installing or child forms.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth can you please take a look at this question, it specifies the problem in details, but no one answered it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771829/reading-mifare-1k-from-a-winform-application

Comment: You almost certainly have a problem with the driver for this device.  The handle is closed a different way when you let the debugger stop the process.  Roughly equivalent to Environment.FailFast().  You don't want to write that kind of code in your app, if you can't get a driver update or support from the vendor (unlikely) then ditch the reader and find another one.

Comment: Thats what I'm afraid of, I'll see what can I do